# Consuming a WCF Rest Service with WP7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, rest

I have a WCF Restful Service that returns JSON objects that my iPhone and Android apps consume nicely. This is my first attempt at building something like this and I left WP7 till last as my background lies with C# and VS2010. But it seems it’s not going to be a simple as I had guessed.

So I guess I have three questions:

1, Can I consume JSON objects in WP7? If so does anyone know of a tutorial?
2, if not, can I use the existing service and build some new contracts for consumption in WP7? Or,

3, do I need to build a whole new service?

Option one is most desirable but either way, I need to develop for all three operating systems so does anyone know the best type of model to bring this all together???
Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, but not with the channel factory / proxy programming model which you may be used to with WCF. REST services are usually consumed by using some simpler classes such as `WebClient`. You can use the JSON libraries (`DataContractJsonSerializer` is in the WP7 profile) then to deserialize the data you receive. Even the untyped JSON (the `System.Json` classes from the System.Json.dll on Silverlight), while not officially in the profile, they kind of work on WP7 as well (I've seen a few people simply referencing the SL library on a WP7 project).
2. If you want proxy support, you can add a new endpoint to the service using `BasicHttpBinding`, which is supported in WP7; if you don't need it, see 1).
3. No. See 1) and 2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to deserialize a JSON object:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string strData) where T : class
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    T tRet = serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as T;
    memoryStream.Dispose();
    return tRet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a totally wcf-based approach more interesting.

This is a good post that addresses this issue
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/04/29/consuming-rest-json-services-in-silverlight-4.aspx